# WSO2 APIM 3.1.0 doesn't start and gives JAVA_HOME missing error when installed via installer

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have installed WSO2 APIM 3.1.0 via product installer on my local. As, in the documentation it's written "If you are using the product installer to install the product, by default, WSO2 API-M is installed with OpenJDK, which allows you to run the product as soon as it is installed.", so, i have not set JAVA_HOME explicitly. But when i run the wso2server.bat command, it gives an error as shown below. Need help with this issue.

[image]

Comment: When you are executing this you are not running the installer. You are executing the binary installation.

Comment: Thanks I got it, then do i need to just click on the API Manager 3.1.0 shortcut to run APIM? If i click on it, the cmd opens and vanishes immediately.

Comment: Have you tried with explicitly setting up JAVA_HOME ?

Answer (score -1):

I tried by setting JAVA_HOME to jdk 11 that comes with the APIM 3.1.0 installer. But when trying to start the server getting the error as seen below:

[image]